# How to Axios post with form-data

Tags: typescript, axios, electron, wireshark, form-data

The contents of form data are not reflected in post.
How can I post form data?

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const axios = require('axios').default;
const FormData = require('form-data');
import { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from 'axios';

//  ******   Excerpt ********
  let csvFile: any;
  promiseFileOpen(file)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('AAA ## ' + res);
      csvFile = res;

      let url = '';
      url += config.URL+ 'post';
      console.log(url);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('foo', csvFile, {
        filename: 'myCSV',
        contentType: 'text/csv',
      });

      //*2
      formData.submit(url, (err: any, res: any) => {
        if (err) console.log('formdata submit Error');

        console.log(res.statusCode);
      });

      //*1
      (async () => {
        await axios
          .post(url, formData, {
            headers: {
              ...formData.getHeaders(),
            },
          })
          .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
            console.log('AxiosResponse->' + response.data);
          })
          .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
            console.log('axios error =>' + error);
          });
      })();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error->' + err));
```

## Log with Wireshark

#### *1 Axios post

```
MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/form-data, Boundary: "--------------------------317363921338863873185030"
    [Type: multipart/form-data]
    Data (17 bytes)
        Data: b6f626a65637420466f726d446174615d
        [Length: 17]
```

#### *2 form-data submit (It looks good. but cannot be used because the session ID cannot be inherited)

```
MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/form-data, Boundary: "--------------------------110980606495398123589222"
    [Type: multipart/form-data]
    First boundary: ----------------------------110980606495398123589222\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part:  (text/csv)
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="eeeeleleele"; filename="electron"\r\n
        Content-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\n
        Media Type
            Media type: text/csv (189 bytes)
    Last boundary: \r\n----------------------------110980606495398123589222--\r\n
```

#### ARC Rest client App (This works right)

```
MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/form-data, Boundary: "--------------------------332315644361122399636534"
    [Type: multipart/form-data]
    First boundary: ----------------------------332315644361122399636534\r\n
    Encapsulated multipart part:  (application/vnd.ms-excel)
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="aaaaabc3332"; filename="putjobCSV.csv"\r\n
        Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel\r\n\r\n
        Media Type
            Media type: application/vnd.ms-excel (189 bytes)
    Last boundary: \r\n----------------------------332315644361122399636534--\r\n
```

Any help is welcome and thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score -1):

Axios can not post multipart/formdata...X(
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318